# PHP - Get a specific object from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having troubles getting one variable from an array.

If I **echo** the array it looks like this:

```
echo print_r($order_total_modules);
```

And it prints out this:

```
    order_total Object ( 
         [modules] => Array ( 
                [0] => ot_quantity_discount.php 
                [1] => ot_shipping.php 
                [2] => ot_subtotal.php 
                [3] => ot_tax.php 
                [4] => ot_total.php 
     ) )
```

I would like to print out only this part: `[1] => ot_shipping.php`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$order_total_modules` is an object, object access notation is `->`, then you have `module` which is an array and normal array notation is with `[]`:

```
$order_total_modules->modules[1]; //returns ot_shipping.php
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new to PHP and I don't use it much and that really helped me.